Flutter assembleDebug fails for processDebugManifest FileNotFound
I have an empty flutter application, which works for chrome.
However, when I try to run it for an emulated android device, I get the following error:
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
...\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

When looking into that folder, I can indeed not find that file.
When running flutter doctor -v, I get no issues. What is going wrong here, any suggestions on how to fix this?
